# Закругленное меню css

Tags: css

Как сделать закругленное меню по средствам css 
На подобе данного http://www.overpro.ru/upload/uploads/Bezyimyannyiy_1371927225.png
Если меню выводится кодом из php Файла.

зарание благодарен.

Comment: Скорей linear-gradient;

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Answer (score 2):

border-radius: ; что ли?

Comment: Нет нужно чтобы ссылки на разделы были в закругленно расположены.